# How do you make a video play automatically on a wpf program startup using a MediaElement

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, mediaelement

I'm sorry if this comes off as a rookie question, but I have spent more time on this than I care to admit.

I'm trying to have a video autoplay on the program's startup. The main window preview shows that the video has been found; however, when I start the program I get a white screen. If someone could help me that would be much appreciated. Thank you and have a wonderful day!

Below is the entirety of the program's xaml code. I have tried running it in other builds of visual studios with no success - so I don't think it's vs.

```
<Window x:Class="SUP.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SUP"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <MediaElement Name="VidPlayer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="321" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="518" Source="Videos\Vid.mp4" LoadedBehavior="Play"></MediaElement>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: Have you set the LoadedBehavior to Manual and tried playing it just to make sure the video itself works?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that :/

Comment: The same code with some video file located on my computer works correctly and start automatically.

Comment: Weird, I have spent literally four hours trying to get this to work. Maybe it's my default project settings I have hidden somewhere. I know this is asking a lot, but, is there a way you could upload your build to Dropbox, or something, and send me a link to it? That way I can narrow down the cause.

Comment: Here you go : https://github.com/RodgerLeblanc/WpfVideoDemo

Comment: Thank you so much! It works witch is so strange. I will let you know if I figure out why.

Comment: @MountainMan could you figure out why?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure your video file has `Copy To Ouput Directory` set to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.

[image: Copy to output directory]